# How to implement coap observer with block2 in Contiki OS

Tags: rest, iot, contiki, coap

I will explain setup first;

Setup: I have a microcontroller board running a Coap rest server (using Contiki OS) with an observable resource and a client (using Coapthon - python library for the Coap) observing that resource running on a Linux SOM. I am successfully able to observe a small amount of data (64 bytes)from the server (microcontroller) to the client (Linux SOM). I will add code at the end after describing everything.

Question: I need help in sending a big chunk of data (suppose 1024 bytes) from the Coap server to the client observer. How can I do that (thanks in advance for any kind of help, I will appreciate for any help I can get regarding this)?

I am posting Contiki observable resource code and the coapthon client code (I am posting the code which not sending big data).
Contiki Code:

```
char * temp_payload = "Behold empty data";

PERIODIC_RESOURCE(res_periodic_ext_temp_data,
         "title=\"Temperature\";rt=\"Temperature\";obs",
         res_get_handler_of_periodic_ext_temp_data,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         res_delete_handler_ext_temp_data,
         (15*CLOCK_SECOND),
         res_periodic_handler_of_ext_temp_data);

static void
res_get_handler_of_periodic_ext_temp_data(void *request, void *response, uint8_t *buffer, uint16_t preferred_size, int32_t *offset)
{
    /*
     * For minimal complexity, request query and options should be ignored for GET on observable resources.
     * Otherwise the requests must be stored with the observer list and passed by REST.notify_subscribers().
     * This would be a TODO in the corresponding files in contiki/apps/erbium/!
     */
    /* Check the offset for boundaries of the resource data. */
    if(*offset >= 1024) {
        REST.set_response_status(response, REST.status.BAD_OPTION);
        /* A block error message should not exceed the minimum block size (16). */
        const char *error_msg = "BlockOutOfScope";
        REST.set_response_payload(response, error_msg, strlen(error_msg));
        return;
    }
    REST.set_header_content_type(response, REST.type.TEXT_PLAIN);
    REST.set_response_payload(response,(temp_payload + *offset), MIN( (int32_t)strlen(temp_payload) - *offset, preferred_size));
    REST.set_response_status(response, REST.status.OK);
    /* IMPORTANT for chunk-wise resources: Signal chunk awareness to REST engine. */
    *offset += preferred_size;
    /* Signal end of resource representation. */
    if(*offset >= (int32_t)strlen( temp_payload) + 1) {
        *offset = -1;
    }
    REST.set_header_max_age(response, MAX_AGE);
}
```

I am not adding code for periodic handler, get handler is getting notified from periodic handler periodically.
Coapthon code:

```
def ext_temp_data_callback_observe(response):  
    print response.pretty_print()

def observe_ext_temp_data(host, callback):
    client = HelperClient(server=(host, port))
    request = Request()
    request.code = defines.Codes.GET.number
    request.type = defines.Types["CON"]
    request.destination = (host, port)
    request.uri_path = "data/res_periodic_ext_temp_data"
    request.content_type = defines.Content_types["text/plain"]
    request.observe = 0
    request.block2 = (0, 0, 64)
    try:
        response = client.send_request(request, callback)
        print response.pretty_print()
    except Empty as e:
        print("listener_post_observer_rate_of_change({0}) timed out". format(host))
```

Again, I need help in implementing observer with coap block wise transfer (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7959#page-26).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell much about the particular systems you use, but in general the combination of block-wise transfer and observes works in that the server only sends the first block of the updated resource. It is then up to the client to ask for the remaining blocks, and to verify that their ETag options match.

The contiki code looks like it should be sufficient, as it sets the offset to -1 which probably sets the "more data" bit in the block header.

On the coapython side, you may need to do reassembly manually, or ask that coapython do the reassembly automatically (its code does not indicate that it'd support the combination of blockwise and observe, at least not at a short glance).

Answer (score 0):

To "bootstrap" your development you may consider to use [Eclipse/Californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium).
The simple client in demo-apps/cf-helloworld-client requires some change for the observe. If you need help, just open an issue in github.

With a two years of experience with that function, let me mention, that, if your data changes faster than your "bandwidth" is able to transfer (including the considered RTT for the blocks), you may send a lot of blocks in vain.
If the data changes just faster than your last block could be send, that invalidates the complete transfer so far. Some start then to develop their work-around, but from that your on very thin ice :-).